# Rails: shell command in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rake, rvm

I'm trying to run shell command with rake task of another project in rails controller:

```
def generate
  render json: `cd /Users/user/project && rvm use ruby-2.1.1@gemset && bundle exec rake users:build`
end
```

The problem is that not working for that task (nothing happening) but if I run `rake routes` for example it is running well.

Comment: @downvoter, how should I edit my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running another ruby project, make sure you clean the current bundler environment before run command. Bundler provides an easy way to tackle this inconvenient by doing:

```
 Bundler.with_clean_env{   
    render json:  `cd /Users/user/project  && rvm use ruby-2.1.1@gemset && BUNDLE_GEMFILE=path/to/Gemfile bundle exec rake users:build`
 }
```

take note of BUNDLE_GEMFILE and Bundler.with_clean_env

Best!

Comment: seems it's not working - `Bundler.with_clean_env` I need to run `bundle install` because gems not found

Comment: are you using rvm or rbenv ? maybe you have to set the proper ruby version to run that command on that app

Comment: I'm using rvm. I've updated my question - added choosing a ruby version with right gemset, but it's still not working - nothing happening

Comment: set BUNDLE_GEMFILE option point to the Gemfile file. I've updated the example code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of issuing a system call, can you try this (place the following snippet in your controller file):

```
require 'rake'

Rake::Task["users:build"]
```

Comment: is it possible to run rake task which is from another project?

Comment: @PavelBabin, since rake files are essentially ruby files, create a blank rake task file in your current project with the same name (as for users:build) and simply include the eternal rake task file in your rake task file.

Comment: thanks for advice, but I need to run a rake task from directory of other project - this is the main problem